# Chrome extension inner file blocked in incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

I'm developing a chrome extension that has the following files for example:

```
test.html
manifest.json
```

Let's say the extension has the id `aaaaaaaaaaaaa`.

If I navigate to the following URL
`chrome-extension://aaaaaaaaaaaaa/test.html`

I can successfully view the `popup.html` file loaded.

However when I try to access the same URL in incognito mode I get a Chrome error with the message:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa is blocked

Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
Try disabling your extensions.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

I have enabled the `Allow in incognito` checkbox in the extension's settings. Is this the browser's intended behaviour? Is there a way to make the file load in incognito mode?

BTW, my `manifest.json` file has

```
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "test.html"
],
...
```

Comment: Are you using spanning mode in manifest? [Won't work](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito).

Comment: @wOxxOm you're right, I was not specifying anything, therefore the default spanning mode was the cause. Now I'm facing another issue regarding having an unshared localStorage, but as the docs say I should probably should be using `chrome.storage` APIs. Could you post your comment as an answer to flag it as resolved?

Comment: relevant link https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito